# Sed / Awk command to format text assigned to varibale

Tags: sed, awk

I have the following input assigned to a variable:

```
echo $var1
abc001: text goes here yyy003: text goes here uuuu004: text goes here
```

The output should be as follow ( without the colon: ) basically I want to print each list starting with the hostname on a new line without the colon

```
abc001 text goes here
yyy003 text goes here
uuuu004 text goes here
```

Comment: What happens when you use `echo "$var1"` instead of `echo $var1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` version:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf $i~":"?"\n"$i" ":$i" "}' <<< "$var1"| awk 'NF {sub(/:/,x);print}'
abc001 text goes here
yyy003 text goes here
uuuu004 text goes here
```

---

Another version, based on Fredriks regex:

```
awk '{gsub(/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/,"\n&");gsub(/:|^\n/,x)}1' <<< "$var1"
abc001 text goes here
yyy003 text goes here
uuuu004 text goes here
```

---

And an `sed` version:

```
sed -E 's/://;s/(\w+):/\n\1/g' <<< "$var1"
abc001 text goes here
yyy003 text goes here
uuuu004 text goes here
```

Comment: Works, but give one blank line at start :-)

Comment: ;) I know, and now fixed. Was not meaning to change your post, sorry.  Se my updated post.

Comment: No worries, has to be an easier way though... I'll + yours if you'll + mine :-)

Comment: This is fine . Thanks but my hostnames are all different they can be anything ,, abc001: yyy003:  uuuu004:  .. so I'm not particularly looking for the host1 and host 2 etc ..

Comment: @mattbeyond Updated my version. Not the most clean version, but does work.

Comment: @mattbeyond My second version listed seems to be ok in one single `awk`

Comment: Can  u please explain the second subsitution in ur command sed -E 's/://;s/(\w+):/\n\1/g' <<< "$var1"

Answer (score 1):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
$ gawk 'NR>1{print host, $0}{host=RT}' RS='[[:alnum:]]+:' OFS='\b' <<< $var1
abc001 text goes here
yyy003 text goes here 
uuuu004 text goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
$ echo $var1
host1: text goes here host2: text goes here Host3:text goes here

$ sed -e 's/\([Hh]ost\)/\n\1/g' -e 's/://g' <<< $var1

host1 text goes here 
host2 text goes here 
Host3text goes here
```

Update:

```
$ echo $var1
aaa1: text goes here bbbb0002: text goes here AAAA0012: text goes here

$ sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\+[0-9]\+\)/\n\1/g' -e 's/://g' <<< $var1

aaa1 text goes here 
bbbb0002 text goes here 
AAAA0012 text goes here
```

Comment: Works, but give one blank line at start. And better to use `var1` as in OPs request.

Comment: This is fine . Thanks but my hostnames are all different they can be anything ,, abc001: yyy003:  uuuu004:  .. so I'm not particularly looking for the host1 and host 2 etc ..

Comment: @FredrikPihl You have an extra space after hostname, change to `s/://g`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po '.*?(?=( [^: ]*:|$))' file|sed 's/://'
```

with your example:

```
kent$ echo "abc001: text goes here yyy003: text goes here uuuu004: text goes here"|grep -Po '.*?(?=( [^: ]*:|$))'|sed 's/://'
abc001 text goes here
yyy003 text goes here
uuuu004 text goes here
```